# using .htaccess to append .html behind url path

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

People are coming into my website like this:

`sitename.com/brands/brandA`

But this will cause an 404 error because I actually need them to come to this url

`sitename.com/brands/brandA.html`

How can I append the .html extension automatically when needed when someone enters `sitename.com/brands/*` with no .html extension using the `.htaccess` document.

Comment: Also if there is another way to solve this than using the .htaccess document, feel free to share it with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/brands/(.*)$ /brands/$1.html [L]
```

Comment: That's the mod_rewrite textbook solution. Small correction: It's `$1` instead of `$2`.

Comment: Thanks, this means I'm not getting crazy, I already attempted this solution but it's not rewriting anything, while other entries in the .htaccess document ARE working. Any ideas on why it's not working?

Comment: if there are other entries in the .htaccess then we have to check order of all the rules. is it possible to share full .htaccess file?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it was indeed the order of all the rules, the url already got caught in a previous rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html) for this, too:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options +MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

If a request comes in, that would result in a 404, mod_negotiation takes other headers like the `Accept` into account and looks for files with the same base name but appropriate extensions.

Comment: PS: And you will probably have better chances, if you post questions like this on http://ServerFault.com .

Comment: I posted it here because it's still programming-related, so I guess both websites will do. (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: No, I'm fine with that. Just saying, that if the word "Apache" appears in your question, the experts might sit elsewhere.