# htaccess append missing .html to URL

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to check if the URL ends with `.html` and append it if it's missing. I've tried a solution from a past SO question but I'm having no luck with the testing site:
[htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Previous SO questions:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751329/using-htaccess-to-append-html-behind-url-path), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150290/append-www-into-url-using-htaccess)

So here's a couple tries I've attempted:

**method 1**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/some/thing/(.*)\.html
RewriteRule ^/some/thing/(.*)$ /some/thing/$1.html
```

**method 2**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/some/thing/(.*)$ /some/thing/$1.html
```

Any tips or pointers? Quite new to .htaccess, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the `thing.html` file actually exist on disk, or are you trying aiming to add `.html` to all URIs despite a real file not existing? Are you trying to force the user's browser to redirect to show .html, or rewrite silently, internally?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Hi Michael, we have a struts2 set up to handle how to interpret the URL's, it's just without the `.html` at the end we get a 404 and I'd like to use htaccess to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+.+?\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L,NE,R]
```

Comment: Apologies for my noob-ness, but I'm not quite sure what your code is doing. Is that regex in the RewriteCond?

Comment: `RewriteCond` has `!` which means negation. It is checking whether `.html` extension is NOT already there. It it is not there then `.html` extension gets appended in URI.